# What is this UI component called?

Tags: design, mobile-application, iphone, app

I'm currently doing an app interface, the client is asking me for an specific design but I can't understand what it is, here's the quote:

"bike code lock" kind of structure for date time and table for x?

If you have any references I will appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming they're talking about something like this:[image]

From what you've described, they might be looking for something like classic iOS date spinner, or the Material UI "datetime-local" component found here: https://material-ui.com/components/pickers/

Each number field - day, month, year, hour, minute - can be moved up or down via the keyboard, similar to the single incrementation found in the bike lock. For usability purposes, the Material picker *also* features the ability to type directly into these fields, as well as a traditional calendar picker view. I'd recommend baking in some of these additional features which may be familiar to your users.